# Accessing static constexpr member of template as a constant expression

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I am trying to access a static constexpr member of a class template as a constant expression, where the member is of the same type as the class being defined. MSVC and clang both seem to choke on this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    static A const DEFAULT;

    constexpr A(int value = {}) : _value{ value } {}

    constexpr operator int() const { return _value; }

    int const _value;
};

constexpr A const A::DEFAULT{};

template<typename = void>
struct B_impl
{
    static B_impl const DEFAULT;

    constexpr B_impl(int value = {}) : _value{ value } {}

    constexpr operator int() const { return _value; }

    int const _value;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr B_impl<T> const B_impl<T>::DEFAULT{};

using B = B_impl<>;

template<int N>
constexpr int foo() { return N; }

int main(int, char**) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "A: " << foo<A::DEFAULT>() << "\n"; // IntelliSense hates this
    std::cout << "B: " << foo<B::DEFAULT>() << "\n"; // VC++ and clang die here:
    // MSVC error:  C2975  'N': invalid template argument for 'foo', expected compile-time constant expression
    // clang error:  note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'N'
    return 0;
}
```

[gcc accepts both](https://ideone.com/VaNoL9) `A` and `B` as constant expressions. MSVC and [clang (demo)](http://rextester.com/XYBC97897) accept `A` as a constant expression, and are okay with `B`, unless I try to use it as a constant expression, and then it fails.

The whole reason I am attempting to use a template here is to achieve inline variables without enforcing C++17, as this is meant for use in a header file.

In this stripped down example, I could instead use a static constexpr function which stores a constexpr value, and then return by value (as static constexpr variables are disallowed within constexpr functions, so I couldn't return by reference). The actual code is a bit more complicated though, which I didn't showcase because it obfuscates the underlying problem ([gcc demo](https://ideone.com/kTGdPK)). I am actually trying to store an array of values (*of the type being defined*, so inline constexpr definitions aren't possible), with named references to those values, all of which should be static constexpr.

Again, this works on all three compilers *if I omit the template*, which I don't want to do since this is in a header and I am *trying* to avoid breaking ODR.

Are MSVC and clang bugged for rejecting this templated version, or is gcc letting something slip through that shouldn't be possible?